# Will I know when the Windows 10 files are being downloaded in the background or not?

Tags: download, notifications, windows-10-upgrade

After reserving the free *Windows 10 Upgrade*, and once the download is available, will I be notified if the download is taking place, or will it take place without my knowledge?

The reason I am asking this is because, if I am notified about the taking place of the download, I can keep my PC turned on, connected to the internet.

Comment: Even if you shutdown, the download should resume I think, just from experience from upgrading to 8.1

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati cool. But when u upgraded to Win8.1 did you know if the download was taking place?

Comment: I kept the store open then, and it did show a progress bar.

Comment: @Switch - The upgrade to 8.1 was entirely different.  You did that through the Windows Store.  Windows 10 will be distributed over a Windows Update mechanic.  As data is released your system will download it provided its connected to the internet.  You can always just download the installation media come July 29th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reserving a Windows 10 Upgrade, after a few hours when you click the same Windows-like icon in the taskbar, you will see a window pop up with the message "Download - In Progress", and you can see the download progress by clicking on the button "View Download Progress".

[image]

([Image source](http://pocketnow.com/2015/07/29/force-windows-10-update#comment-2162803169))

My background download is in progress with 20% done. That's all folks!

Comment: This page *might* suggest you can see it in Windows Update as well: https://techjourney.net/force-trigger-download-and-install-of-windows-10-free-upgrade-kb3012973/ (But maybe only if you force-trigger the download. But then I guess people who read this question will do that...?)

Comment: Why the downvote? (I don't use Windows, but I see multiple references to this. That is: once the download has started, obviously.)

Answer (score 3):

No you wont get a notification but if you go to the root of C: then you should see (if enabled) a hidden folder called: "$Windows.~BT" that shows that windows 10 is being downloaded to your computer.

[image: Hidden folder]

You can also download with this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: [Bilal's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/945464/will-i-know-when-the-windows-10-files-are-being-downloaded-in-the-background-or/946732#946732) claims otherwise.

Comment: @Arjan - Bilal's answer is correct.  This answer is also correct.  You are not provided a notification this happens though hence the reason it is correct.

Comment: What size is the Windows-bt folder when fully ready for install?

Comment: around 6gb
But if you dont want to wait use this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 2):

No, I won't be notified regarding the download.

I learn tthis in the thread that I started: [Will I know when the Windows 10 files are being downloaded in the background or not?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/will-i-know-when-the-windows-10-files-are-being/e93b2188-d2f4-4f02-8bb8-66f301c584f6?tm=1437913781590).

The correct answer was posted by an MVP, [Andre Da Costa](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/e5564792-9930-4912-828b-e206924b132a) , and it said:

> No, it won't provide any progress when its actually downloading.

Comment: Note that MVPs are not necessarily Microsoft employees.

Comment: _"Downloading will be a background task."_ Ugh. That is _so_ stupid.

Comment: @Lightness, why is that stupid? It nicely allows Microsoft to control how much traffic is sent to their servers.

Comment: [Bilal's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/945464/will-i-know-when-the-windows-10-files-are-being-downloaded-in-the-background-or/946732#946732) claims otherwise.

Comment: @Arjan: What does "allows Microsoft to control" have to do with transferring in the background with no status indication or pause method? Y'know, those fundamental things that have been on every sensible download mechanism since the 1990s.

Comment: Ah, @Lightness, I didn't understand you were referring to the progress indicator. Yes, lack of that would be stupid, but: [Bilal's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/945464/will-i-know-when-the-windows-10-files-are-being-downloaded-in-the-background-or/946732#946732) might give you some hope?

Comment: @Arjan: Yep, good.